# How to change ngTable title colors programmatically?

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/na57RtXZem4qvRdPTWip?p=preview) I have an ngTable that is created dynamically, setting progammatically the colors of the rows for each column. How to change the colors of the column titles?

HTML:

```
<table ng-table-dynamic="tableParams with cols" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
      <td ng-repeat="col in cols" ng-style="{ 'color': col.color }">{{row[col.nm]}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTable']);

app.controller('myCtl', function($scope,NgTableParams) {

      $scope.cols = [ 
        {nm:'uid', title:'User ID', color: 'blue'}, 
        {nm:'ugr', title: 'Group ID', color: 'red'} 
      ];


      $scope.data = [ 
        { uid: 'aaa',ugr: '222'},
        { uid: 'bbb', ugr: '111'}
      ];

      $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({dataset: $scope.data});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include a thead. Here is an updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/upwV1lZPc1mxCrRntAeE?p=preview)

```
<table ng-table-dynamic="tableParams with cols" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th ng-repeat="col in cols" ng-style="{ 'color': col.color }">{{col.title}}</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
      <td ng-repeat="col in cols" ng-style="{ 'color': col.color }">{{row[col.nm]}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your solution works and is the preferred solution because it allows me to change the colors programmatically without classes. However it breaks the number of rows per page, look at this plunk, the table should show 3 rows per page and not 4. http://plnkr.co/edit/98kvWKgzE8fwgsEjkQce?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `class` property on each of the objects in your `cols` array:

```
$scope.cols = [ 
    {nm:'uid', title:'User ID', class: 'text-blue' }, 
    {nm:'ugr', title: 'Group ID', class: 'text-red'} 
];
```

Then set appropriate css classes in your stylesheet:

```
.text-blue{
  color: #0000ff; 
}

.text-red{
  color: #ff0000; 
}
```

[**Demo Plunk**](http://plnkr.co/edit/dn3ashiaxfBByUXS2Djs?p=preview)

Comment: ok I didn't know it actually supports the class property, hence my solution, I will keep it in case of someone needs future modifications on that headings, but this should be upvoted.

Comment: I need to change the colors programmatically, the colors shouldn't be in classes as they will be stored in a database

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it is Matthew Cawley's answer but in case you want to do additional modifications on table headers it's useful to know that you can change template for header:

http://plnkr.co/edit/662FYVbJyz2wxqXV5nNk?p=preview

```
<table  template-header="table-header.html" ng-table-dynamic="tableParams with cols" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
```

after that add file table-header.html in your project containing this:

```
<tr>
    <th title="{{$column.headerTitle(this)}}"
        ng-repeat="$column in $columns"
        ng-class="{
                    'sortable': $column.sortable(this),
                    'sort-asc': params.sorting()[$column.sortable(this)]=='asc',
                    'sort-desc': params.sorting()[$column.sortable(this)]=='desc',
                  }"
        ng-click="sortBy($column, $event)"
        ng-if="$column.show(this)"
        ng-init="template = $column.headerTemplateURL(this)"
        class="header {{$column.class(this)}} {{$column.headerClass}}">
        <div ng-if="!template" class="ng-table-header" ng-class="{'sort-indicator': params.settings().sortingIndicator == 'div'}">
            <span ng-bind="$column.title(this)" ng-class="{'sort-indicator': params.settings().sortingIndicator == 'span'}"></span>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="template" ng-include="template"></div>
    </th>
</tr>
```

then in your code:

```
$scope.cols = [ 
        {nm:'uid', title:'User ID', headerClass: 'blue'}, 
        {nm:'ugr', title: 'Group ID', headerClass: 'red'} 
      ];
```

also don't forget css classes:

```
.red {
  color: red;
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```